# Unable to mount /home directory using ARM template with Atmoz/SFTP (SSH)

Tags: sftp, openssh, azure-rm-template, azure-container-instances

I'm using the template provided by https://charbelnemnom.com/2019/06/how-to-deploy-sftp-service-on-microsoft-azure/ In that example he mounts a volume specific to the user. This works perfectly. I wanted to change the mount to just mount the "/home" directory so the the FTP server will automatically create user folders under the mounted home directory. When starting the container, the user folders for each user are created when starting the container, but, upon logging in, I get

bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/home/"

I've seen other posts indicating that root must have access to these directories, but I'm confused because it obviously has enough permissions to create the user folders in the mounted home directory. So why would I get the error when the user tries to log in? How would I modify the resource template to allow user folders to be auto-created by the FTP server while also allowing the user to be CHRooted to them?

The following section works:

```
                "volumeMounts": [
                  {
                    "mountPath": "/home/user1",
                    "name": "sftpvolume",
                    "readOnly": false
                  }
                ]
```

This does not work:

```
                "volumeMounts": [
                  {
                    "mountPath": "/home",
                    "name": "sftpvolume",
                    "readOnly": false
                  }
                ]
```

I think the major difference between the two approaches above that, in the first approach that works, the deployment script creates the user directory (which root probably has permission to) whereas if the FTP server creates the user directory when starting, it may not.  But I'm not sure how to address it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the behavior you are observing is related to the underlying docker image [atmoz/sftp](https://hub.docker.com/r/atmoz/sftp/). A note from the "Usage" section of their readme says:

> remember that the users can't create new files directly under their own home directory, so make sure there are at least one subdirectory if you want them to upload files

EDIT: Azure File Share cannot be used with the auto-create user folder feature of this docker image.

The error message you're getting is because the `/home` folder has incorrect permissions (`chroot` requires 755, with root as owner). You can confirm this by starting a shell in your container with `az container exec -g RESOURCE_GROUP -n sftp-group --exec-command /bin/bash` then running `ls -la`. You will see:

```
# ls -la
total 80
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun  6 13:57 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun  6 13:57 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Jun  6 13:57 .dockerenv
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Dec 28  2018 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Oct 20  2018 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  360 Jun  6 13:57 dev
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 2665 Dec 28  2018 entrypoint
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun  6 13:57 etc
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root    0 Jun  6 13:57 home
```

Unfortunately, you will not be able to achieve the specific ownership and permissions structure required to be able to use different users' home folders as `chroot` targets.

The Azure File Share volume is mounted with a single ownership + permissions combination. You cannot change the ownership or permissions on subfolders as would be required for this technique to work.

Comment: Yea I did that, but it didn't resolve it.  the FTP server does create all the directories I specified under each user, they just can't login due to that error.     In this case, they are not uploading any files because they can't even login. 
 ioiUser1:pwUser1:1001:100:upload/phi,download

Comment: I just tried it and I see what you mean - folders are created and user cannot login.

Comment: What if we added a startup script to the container that would loop through all user directories and apply the appropriate permissions?

Comment: The permissions won't change because of how the mount of the volume works. I believe this is a limitation of the CIFS protocol (https://sysadmins.tech/linux-and-cifs-files-permissions/)

Comment: Would you happen to know what is different about when the volume is mounted to the user directory upload folder in the original deployment script that allows it to work?  Just wondering why that can't be replicated in a script.

Comment: So basically, I have to know all the users that will use the sFTP service when I create the container so I can mount the volume at that time?  Right?